# Is this a good way to identify the type of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, types

Apparently neither `instanceof` nor `typeof` deliver in terms of correctly identifying the type of every javascript object. I have come up with this function and I'm looking for some feedback:

```
    function getType() {

        var input = arguments[0] ;

        var types = ["String","Array","Object","Function","HTML"] ; //!! of the top of my head

        for(var n=0; n < types.length; n++) {

            if( input.constructor.toString().indexOf( types[n] ) != -1) {
                document.write( types[n] ) ;
            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on the `instanceof` operator is [not good enough](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) for some cases.

A known problem is that it wonk doesn't work on cross-frame environments.

The `typeof` operator is not so useful, and there are some implementation bugs, for example like in Chrome or Firefox 2.x, where `RegExp` objects are detected as `"function"`, because they have made *callable* (e.g. `/foo/(str);`).

The `constructor` property *can be tampered*, and you should *never* put much trust on it.

And finally, the [`Function.prototype.toString`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.3.4.2) method is *implementation dependent*, meaning that the implementation *may* not include even the function name in the string representation of the function...

Some [days ago](http://gist.github.com/369052) I was building a simple but robust *type detection* function, it uses `typeof` for primitive values, and relies on the [`[[Class]]`](http://gist.github.com/369052) internal property for objects.

All objects have this property, implementations use it internally to detect the *kind* of the object, it is completely *immutable*, and is only accessible through the [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.2.4.2) method:

Usage:

```
//...
if (typeString(obj) == 'array') {
  //..
}
```

Implementation:

```
function typeString(o) {
  if (typeof o != 'object')
    return typeof o;

  if (o === null)
      return "null";
  //object, array, function, date, regexp, string, number, boolean, error
  var internalClass = Object.prototype.toString.call(o)
                                               .match(/\[object\s(\w+)\]/)[1];
  return internalClass.toLowerCase();
}
```

The [second variant](http://gist.github.com/369052#file_type_string_no_host_types.js) of this function is more strict, because it returns only built-in object types described in the ECMAScript specification.

Possible output values:

**Primitives:**

- `"number"`
- `"string"`
- `"boolean"`
- `"undefined"`
- `"null"`
- `"object"`

**Built-in object types** (through `[[Class]]`)

- `"function"`
- `"array"`
- `"date"`
- `"regexp"`
- `"error"`

Comment: You've earned your 74K reputation, CMS.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks! Can you elaborate on why using the `constructor` property is not a good idea as it can be "tampered"?

Comment: @Diobeus, thanks!, @FK82 I mean that the `constructor` property is writable, and a malformed object can give you wrong results, e.g. (`var re = /foo/; re.constructor = null;`), also you might set the wrong `constructor` when implementing inheritance on custom types [without even noticing](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html)...

Comment: @ CMS Alright, thanks again. So, inheritance screws up the constructor. There is no java in javascript after all, is there? :-)

Comment: @FK82: Overriding the entire `prototype` member of constructor functions can screw the `constructor` property... Yes JavaScript is more like "Lisp in C's clothing" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Similar question came up a few days ago. I cracked open jQuery 1.4.2 to see how it has been done there. Here are my results thus far, you can run checks for the rest of them Im sure:

```
(function() {

    // Define the base sys namespace
    this.sys = function() { };

    var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

    //from jQuery 1.4.2    
    sys.isFunction = function(obj) {
        return toString.call(obj) === "[object Function]";
    }

    //from jQuery 1.4.2
    sys.isArray = function(obj) {
        return toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (sys.isArray(myObject)) doStuff();
```

Comment: Looks similar to CMS's technique.

Comment: Yeah. They both seem to be using the same mechanism. Thanks anyway.